# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT env variables pass in docker and kubernetes

Tags: azure-pipelines

We have aspnet core 2.1 application and we are using Azure Pipeline to build and release the application.

We are using docker build to build image in the build pipeline and deploy the application to Kubernetes in the release pipeline.

Now we would like to build the image once and deploy the image to Kubernetes in 3 stages (Development, Staging, and Production).

We are using ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to differentiate the stages. We tried to use this variable in DockerFile and Kubernetes deployment.azure.yaml file. Also, We have configured Docker Profile in launchsettings.json in the application.

```
“Docker”: {
    “commandName”: “Docker”,
        “environmentVariables”: {
        “ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT”: “”,
        “ASPNETCORE_URLS”: “”,
        “DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT”: “Staging”
    }
},
```

But still, the environment variables are not working as expected. Every time we deploy the application to Kubernetes It is taking the Development variable.

Please suggest a better plan or changes achieve “Build Once, Deploy Everywhere” strategy.

Thanks,
Mrugesh

Comment: Have you checked the following reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but in your question you are missing a lot fo details like your DOCKERFILE or kubernetes yaml configuration files. However, based on what you wrote I belive this [article](https://pascalnaber.wordpress.com/2017/11/29/handling-settings-and-environment-variables-of-your-net-core-2-application-hosted-in-a-docker-container-during-development-and-on-kubernetes-helm-to-the-resque/) is your answer.

In short words it moves a bit away of the appsettings files as they may contain secrets and thus they should not go into docker image. And instead of that thay are replaces with helm charts where you pass your secrets as argument. And thus definitely is `Build Once, Deploy Everywhere` approach.

Comment: My DockerFile is below: 

    FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
    COPY . . 
    WORKDIR /src/testService

    RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

    RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app --no-restore

    #RUN export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
    ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS //*:5000
    EXPOSE 5000/tcp

    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]

I tried to use the ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--launch-profile=Staging"] but It doesn't work.

I am using Azure Devops CI-CD Pipeline to build docker image and run that image on kubernetes.